# Trying to append Fetch Data from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, promise, fetch-api

I am sorry to keep posting what looks like the same request, but I tried using what I believe to be a correct(?) function of promise all for my page to pull JSON data from an array of URLs and append them to a div container, and I still have no results. Any help in pointing out what I am missing or doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. Please keep in mind that I am an absolute beginner to using JavaScript, and so probably won't implicitly understand the features people mention.

```
//const url = 'https://fategrandorder.fandom.com/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Abigail%20Williams&rvprop=content&format=json'
const baseURL = 'https://fategrandorder.fandom.com/api.php';
const servantTitle = ['Artoria_Pendragon', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Alter)', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Lily)', 'Nero_Claudius', 'Siegfried', 'Gaius_Julius_Caesar', 'Altera', 'Gilles_de_Rais_(Saber)', "Chevalier_d'Eon", 'Okita_Sōji', 'Fergus_mac_Róich', 'Mordred', 'Nero_Claudius_(Bride)', 'Ryōgi_Shiki_(Saber)', 'Rama, Water_Iri', 'Lancelot_Saber', 'Gawain', 'Bedivere', 'Elizabeth_Báthory_(Brave)', 'Miyamoto_Musashi', 'Arthur_Pendragon_(Prototype)', 'Suzuka_Gozen', 'Frankenstein_(Saber)', 'Yagyū_Munenori', 'Sigurd', 'Medb_(Saber)', 'Diarmuid_Ua_Duibhne', 'Lanling_Wang', 'Beni-enma', 'Lakshmibai', 'Jason', 'Katsushika_Hokusai_(Saber)', 'Astolfo_(Saber)', 'Dioscuri', 'Tomoe_Gozen_(Saber)', 'Saitō_Hajime'];

let url;

for (let title in servantTitle) {
  url = baseURL + '&prop=revisions&titles=' + servantTitle[title] + '&rvprop=content&format=json';
  console.log(url)
}

Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url)))
  .then(resp => Promise.all(resp.map(r => r.json())))
  .then(result => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        appendData(json);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('error: ' + err);
      });

    function appendData(json) {
      var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");

      //alert(json[0].stars);

      for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + json[i].aka + /n'Class: ' + json[i].class + /n
        'Attack: ' + json[i].atk + /n'HP: ' + json[i].hp + /n
        'Grail Attack: ' + json[i].gatk + /n"Grail HP: ' + ${json[i].ghp} + /n
        'Stars: ' + json[i].stars + /n'Cost: ' + json[i].cost;
        mainContainer.appendChild(div);
      }
    }

  })
```

Comment: Where do you set `urls`?

Comment: What's the point of the `for (let title in servantTitle)` loop?

Comment: In your `for` you re-assign `url` over and over again... I think this is likely an error

Comment: why is fetch in there twice

Comment: The code that sets `URLs` in your last question is correct. Why did you change that part?

Comment: [Title] is referring, I believe, to the title aspect in the JSON data. to @Dominik , how would I fix that if it is indeed an error?

Comment: Since I am a beginner to coding, please show me what the correct one would be, since I have been forced to rapidly expand beyond my knowledge area for this project. I am learning on the fly here with each aspect of the code

Comment: Whats the point of that Promise.all wrapping the second fetch? Its result is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You have tried to try to capture the error to be able to obtain traceability?

```
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error(data);
});
```

to make sure you get data

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's jump straight in.

First thing, you are trying to map through the list of URL's, but you don't have that list.

```js
Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url)))
```

`urls` array is not defined in your code.

Instead of going point by point, I'm going to paste a code suggestion. Take a look at it, and if you see something you don't understand, be free to ask ;-)

NOTE: The API you provided did not return a valid JSON to me, so I couldn't validate this actually work.

Don't consider this to be the final solution, it should serve as a mental image.

```js
const baseURL = 'https://fategrandorder.fandom.com/api.php';
const servantTitles = ['Artoria_Pendragon', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Alter)', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Lily)', 'Nero_Claudius', 'Siegfried', 'Gaius_Julius_Caesar', 'Altera', 'Gilles_de_Rais_(Saber)', "Chevalier_d'Eon", 'Okita_Sōji', 'Fergus_mac_Róich', 'Mordred', 'Nero_Claudius_(Bride)', 'Ryōgi_Shiki_(Saber)', 'Rama, Water_Iri', 'Lancelot_Saber', 'Gawain', 'Bedivere', 'Elizabeth_Báthory_(Brave)', 'Miyamoto_Musashi', 'Arthur_Pendragon_(Prototype)', 'Suzuka_Gozen', 'Frankenstein_(Saber)', 'Yagyū_Munenori', 'Sigurd', 'Medb_(Saber)', 'Diarmuid_Ua_Duibhne', 'Lanling_Wang', 'Beni-enma', 'Lakshmibai','Jason', 'Katsushika_Hokusai_(Saber)', 'Astolfo_(Saber)', 'Dioscuri', 'Tomoe_Gozen_(Saber)', 'Saitō_Hajime'];

// Compose list of URL's using the baseURL and each servant from the servantTitles array
const URLs = servantTitles.map(title => `${baseURL}&prop=revisions&titles=${title}&rvprop=content&format=json`);

// Create array of promises returned by the fetch call to each of URL's 
const apiCalls = URLs.map(URL => fetch(URL));

// Wait for all fetch calls to be resolved and return the promisees
Promise.all(apiCalls)

   // and get JSON data from each promise returned by the fetch call
   .then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(response => response.json())))

   // append data to html element
   .then(data => {
      var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");

      data.forEach(servant => {
         // Here you have the servant data and you can append it to your main container as you wish
      });
   });
```

Comment: the url query is wrong and will fail. it should be ´`${baseURL}?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=${title}&rvprop=content&format=json`´

Comment: @Dejan Thank you very much for that simplification of code. here is an example of a working JSON URL for which I am trying to pull from. https://fategrandorder.fandom.com/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Abigail%20%20Williams&rvprop=content&format=json         I found that if I simply transpose the name of the Servant, it should still be applicable as I tested the swap out for multiple names